# Evitar 504 Gateway Time-out con archivo PHP

Tags: php, php7, apache2

Tengo un archivo recursivo que debe hacer un sinfín de consultas a la Base de datos, modificaciones, eliminaciones, etc.

Limite el listado para poder ejecutarlo por lotes más pequeños y el tiempo es menor.

Pero en algunos casos salta el **504 Gateway Time-out**. (Se ha subido el límite en el servidor)

He pensado dos soluciones:

1-  Utilizara el ***set_time_limit()*** / ***ini_set('memory_limit','1000')*** para controlar el tiempo. De tal forma que sepa el tiempo que dispongo antes de que se agote y actuar en consecuencia antes de llegar al punto crítico.

2- utilizar ***shell_exec()*** para ejecutar el script en segundo plano directamente.

Desconozco si la opción 2  soluciona el problema del 504.

***Qué opción me recomiendan?***

La idea es que antes de que colapse todo, tenga tiempo a por ejemplo... parar el proceso de forma controlada y almacenar un dato en la BBDD o algo similar... . El detalle del tipo de control es lo de menos, lo interesante es saber si uno se puede anticipar al colapso y actuar en consecuencia.

Comment: ¿Intentaste colocar al inicio del archivo php el límite de la memoria?, por ejemplo: ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');

Comment: He estado leyendo y me parece que el *ini_set* en alojamientos compartidos no funciona.

Comment: Eduardo tienes razón. Pero en tu archivo php (No me refiero a php.ini) al inicio puedes establecer el límite de tiempo y memoria, prueba así.

Comment: Sí a eso me refiero. tengo entendido que el uso de `ini_set` esta bloqueado en algunos servidores sobretodo compartidos. Por lo tanto los cambios con `ini_set` seguramente en localhost funcionan pero luego en producción no.

Comment: 1.- Podrias calcular o sacar una media para el tamaño de tus lotes, dejando un margen de tiempo para cuando va a terminarse el tiempo. 2 puedes optar por mudarte a un servidor dedicado. 3 montar tu propio servidor contratar una IP publica que apunte a tu servidor. No se, son las cosas que se me ocurren, jaja.

Comment: @JCLXS La idea es aplicarlo en un módulo de Prestashop, que puede estar en varios tipos de Servidores. Lo he probado en un servidor dedicado, y se le ha puesto el `memory_limit` bastante alto. Y ese no es el problema, ni la cuestión. La pregunta básicamente es... Cual de las opciones propuestas o otras posibles, son eficientes para evitar entrar en un 504-Timeout. La cuestión es dotar al sistema de esta funcionalidad para evitar caídas de este tipo.